# Framework7 for PhoneGap multiplatform application, switch between iOS and Material is automatic?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I need to implement an hybrid mobile app for Android and iOS.
I'm looking for the solution Framework7 + PhoneGap.
I've seen that Framework7 includes css to replicate look and feel of both Android and iOS. Question: is Framework7 able to automatical switch the look and feel based on the app (Android app or iOS app) or do I need to implement 2 different apps (1 for Android and 1 for iOS) or maybe I need to implement a specific custom check on the load of the application?

thank you for your help!

d

Answer (score 0):

We used two ways:

- Conditions for code (or in template) (http://framework7.io/docs/device.html).
- CSS-rules for display elements of specific platform (.ios, .md).

Furthermore: Set theme: "auto" in app parameters and it will switch theme automatically